# What is the exact length of $("#dialog").html(message)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-dialog

I am using `Jquery Dialog` and the length of message is too large. I am using the following code

**JavaScript**

```
function ShowPopup(message) {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "New words result",
            resizable: true,
            height: "auto",
            width:"900px",
            buttons: {
               },
            modal: true
        });
    });
};
```

**C#**

```
string sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vConnString"].ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
string QUERY = "Sproc_FindNewWords";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QUERY, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AM_AssetID", ddlGroup.SelectedItem.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i]["val"].ToString()!="")
        {
            sb.Append("<span>" + dt.Rows[i]["val"].ToString() + "</span>,&nbsp;"); 
        }               
    }          
}

string message = sb.ToString();         
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
```

I want to know about what is the exact length of `$("#dialog").html(message);`
When the message text is small it's working fine and in the same way when text is too large it's not working.

**OR**

Any other way to show the result on `Jquery Dialog` please suggest.

Comment: you can check the length of the message by simply doing `console.log(message.length);`. The length message can come up when working with Webservices. Is it a Webservice you are using?

Comment: No i am calling the function on `Button_Click` event

Comment: Have you tried this - http://roam.be/notebook/2012/jquery-dialog-keep-your-hands-of-my-content.html, to wrap text in Jquery dialog, or use `auto` in width instead of `900px`.

Answer (score 0):

Take Div in aspx ;

```
<div id="divmessage" style='display:none' runat='server'/>
```

in aspx.cs

```
divmessage.innerHTML=message;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);
```

in jquery

```
function ShowPopup() {
var message=$("#divmessage").html();
if(message.length>0)
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").html(message);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "New words result",
        resizable: true,
        height: "auto",
        width:"900px",
        buttons: {
           },
        modal: true
    });
});
```

};